# Set icon for multiple folders/shortcuts at once

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I have multiple folders all with an ico file in them with the same name (cover). Can I make a batch script that will take all the folders in a directory and set there icon to the ico folder inside them. Also could I make a script that will do the same thing but with shortcuts to the folders instead of the folders themselves.

Comment: Get inspired with this [batch file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8d4389txc14k15r/Hackoo_Icon_Folder_Changer.rar)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this batch file : **[Hackoo_Change_Icon_Folder.bat](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8d4389txc14k15r/Hackoo_Icon_Folder_Changer.rar)**

```bat
@echo off
Title %~nx0 by Hackoo 2017
mode con cols=80 lines=3 & Color 9E
if _%1_==_Main_  goto :Main
:getadmin
    echo(
    echo               "%~nx0" : Running Admin Shell
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
(
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "Main %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1
)> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof
::**********************************************************************************
:Main
set "fld=%userprofile%\Desktop\Hackoo"
set "ico=%~dp0icon.ico"
md "%fld%\icons" >nul 2>&1
echo(
echo   Please wait a while... we execute the commands to change icon to the folder
If exist "%ico%" (
    Attrib -s "%ico%"
) else (
    cls & mode con cols=85 lines=3 & color 0C
    echo( 
    echo  The file "icon.ico" should be in the same folder as "%~nx0"
    Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & exit
)
if exist "%ico%" ( copy "%ico%" "%fld%\icons\icon.ico" /y >nul 2>&1 )
if exist "%fld%\desktop.ini" ( attrib -h -s -a "%fld%\desktop.ini" >nul 2>&1 )

(
    echo [.ShellClassInfo]
    echo IconResource=icons\icon.ico,0
)> "%fld%\Desktop.ini"

attrib +h +s +a "%fld%\Desktop.ini"
attrib +r "%fld%"
attrib +h "%fld%\icons"
Rem To refresh the explorer by killing and restart it
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f >nul & start explorer

If "%ErrorLevel%" EQU "0" (
    cls & echo( & color 9E
    echo                     The commands are executed successfully !
    Timeout /T 4 /nobreak>nul
    Explorer.exe /e,/root,"%fld%"
) else (
    cls & echo( & color 0C
    echo         There was an error occured while this program is running !
    Timeout /T 4 /nobreak>nul
)
```

Comment: whenever i try to get into the Desktop.ini is gives back Access is denied

Answer (score 0):

I did it I finally did it, this project turned out to be way more then I bargained for but I persevered and got it working. So now I would like to share with you all the scripts I wrote. i had to combine both batch files and vbs files but who cares as long as its working.

first script part 1 bat

```
@echo off
rem //comment - file name is FolderIconToCoverPart1Of2.bat
rem //comment – file name of part 2 vbs script is FolderIconToCoverPart2Of2.vbs
rem //comment - this batch file changes all the folders in its directory to use an ico file inside of themselves called cover.ico.
rem //comment - in windows icon information for a folder in stored in a hidden file inside of every folder called desktop.ini
rem //comment - in order for the folder to update its icon the desktop.ini file must be created somewhere else and then moved to the folder using a vbs script
rem //comment - bat files can't update a desktop.ini
rem //comment - The desktop.ini is created first in %temp% which refers to the temp folder for the current user
rem //comment - “C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp”

rem //comment - for /D loops thorugh the folders 
rem //comment - %%~fi & %%~fi% directs to the path of the current folder the loop is on with i being the variable declared in the loop itself

for /D %%i in (*) do (

        rem //comment - checks if the desktop.ini exist if it does we need to change the attributes before editing it
    rem //comment - If the desktop.ini does not exist the program will make a new file latter in the script
    if exist "%temp%\desktop.ini" (
        echo file found
        attrib -h -s -r "%temp%\desktop.ini"
    ) else (
        echo no file found makeing new one
    )
    rem //comment - end of if

    echo setting icon in "%%~fi"

    rem //comment - this sets the folder to make use of the desktop.ini file inside of it
    attrib +r +s %%~fi

    rem //comment - puts the new text into the desktop.ini file inside of the temp folder
    rem //comment - if the file does not exist its makes a new one automatically 
    (echo [.ShellClassInfo] 
    echo IconResource=%%~fi\cover.ico) > "%temp%\desktop.ini"

    rem //comment - passes arguments to vbs script
    rem //comment - The arguments are the path of the current folder the loop is on and the path of the temp folder (were the desktop.ini is stored)
    "FolderIconToCoverPart2Of2" "%%~fi" "%temp%

    rem //comment - returns the desktop.ini file attributes to their original form
    attrib +h +s -r %%~fi%\Desktop.ini

)
rem //comment - end of for loop

pause
```

first script part 2 vbs

```
rem //comment – file name is FolderIconToCoverPart2Of2.vbs
rem //comment – file name of part 1 bat file is FolderIconToCoverPart1Of2.bat
rem //comment - This vbs script is the second part of a batch script it has two argument passed to by that batch
rem //comment - The arguments are the path of the current folder the loop is on and the path of the temp folder (were the desktop.ini is stored)

rem //comment - creates an variable object that holds the arguments passed in by the batch
set args = Wscript.arguments

rem //comment - gets the first and second argument from args and holds them in variables
PathToFolder = args(0) 
TempFolder = args(1)

rem //comment - converts Path to the temp folder to a string
rem //comment - then adds on the \Desktop.ini for a complete file path
TempDeskTopIni = CStr(TempFolder) + "\" + "Desktop.ini"


rem //comment - Not sure what this is I just know its needed 
rem //comment - I think it has something to do with accessing methods built into the os itself (if anybody knows more pls tell me)
set shell = CreateObject ("Shell.Application")


rem //comment Creates and returns a folder object for the specified folder
set CurrentDirectory = shell.NameSpace( PathToFolder )


rem //comment - Takes the desktop.ini created in the temp folder and puts into the current directory the loop is on in the batch
CurrentDirectory.MoveHere TempDesktopIni, 4+16+1024
```

second script part 1 batch

```
@echo off
rem //comment - file name is ShortcutIconToCoverPart1Of2.bat
rem //comment – file name of part 2 vbs script is ShortcutIconToCoverPart2Of2.vbs
rem //comment - This batch file takes all the lnk shortcuts in its directory and changes there icon to a file called cover.ico inside of their target path
rem //comment - The actual changeing of the icon is done by a vbs script that has the current directory the loop is on passed to it as an argument

rem //comment - loops though all the files with the lnk extension and passes its path to the vbs script
rem //comment - %%~fi & %%~fi% directs to the path of the current folder the loop is on with i being the variable declared in the loop itself

for %%i in ("*.lnk") do (
    echo file found changing icon to cover.ico %%~fi
    rem //comment - pass the current lnk file the loop is on to the vbs script
    "ShortcutIconToCoverPart2Of2" "%%~fi"
)
rem //comment - end of for loop

pause
```

second scropt part 2 vbs

```
rem //comment - file name is ShortcutIconToCoverPart2Of2.vbs
rem //comment – file name of part 1 bat script is ShortcutIconToCoverPart1Of2.bat
rem //comment - this vbs script takes the file path of a lnk passed to it and changes it icon to a file called cover.ico inside of its target path

rem //comment - creates an variable object that holds the arguments passed in by the batch
set args = Wscript.arguments

rem //comment - gets the first argument from args and holds it in the variable PathToLnk 
PathToLnk = args(0)

rem //comment - Not sure what this is I just know its needed 
rem //comment - I think it has something to do with accessing methods built into the os itself (if anybody knows more pls tell me)
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

rem //comment - saves the PathToLnk variable as a shortcut object
Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(PathToLnk)

rem //comment - sets the lnk variable icon path
lnk.IconLocation = lnk.TargetPath + "\cover.ico"

rem //comment - saves changes made to the lnk file with this script
lnk.Save
```